# thread.setPriority(0) is giving IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, illegalargumentexception

When I run this code, it gave me `IllegalArgumentException`, then whole code was executed, but the name of thread t was default one only and not Mark as per the code.

What could be the reason?

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.lang.Thread.setPriority(Unknown Source)
        at Threads.CurrentThreadImpl.main(CurrentThreadImpl.java:11)
    value of I is : 0and the thread name is : Thread-0
    value of I is : 1and the thread name is : Thread-0
    value of I is : 2and the thread name is : Thread-0
    value of I is : 3and the thread name is : Thread-0
    value of I is : 0and the thread name is : Thread-1
    value of I is : 1and the thread name is : Thread-1
    value of I is : 2and the thread name is : Thread-1
    value of I is : 3and the thread name is : Thread-1
```

---

```
    public class CreateThread implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            System.out.println("value of I is : "+ i + "and the thread name is : "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

    public class CurrentThreadImpl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateThread runnableObj = new CreateThread();
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnableObj);
        Thread t = new Thread(runnableObj);
        thread.start();
        t.start();
        thread.setPriority(0);
        t.setPriority(10);
        t.setName("Mark");
    }

}
```

Comment: see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Thread.MAX_PRIORITY) what are the values for MIN/MAX priority

Answer (score 8):

See [Thread#setPriority](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29):

> IllegalArgumentException - If the priority is not in the range
>   **MIN_PRIORITY** to **MAX_PRIORITY**.

[`MIN_PRIORITY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Thread.MIN_PRIORITY) is 1, not 0:

[image]

Comment: Thats ok ... but if I am giving wrong priority even then code is working. Why it is not getting stopped just after giving error? Is there any specifc reason?

Comment: @user2450176 The thread doing the thread creation was stopped, or at least the method completed abruptly. That is why the thread name change never happened. The two threads it started had not experienced any exceptions, and carried on running.

Answer (score 4):

Priorities go from 1 to 10.

```
Thread.MIN_PRIORITY (1)
Thread.NORM_PRIORITY (5)
Thread.MAX_PRORITY (10)
```